# Unhide cursor in Cocoa screensaver

Tags: cocoa, cursor, screensaver

I’m developing a Mac OS X screensaver that uses WebView. WebView loads flash with a map. I want to let a user move the map and resize it (flash map has appropriate controls). I’ve redefine mouseMoved: method so the screensaver does not exit on mouse move. But the mouse cursor is still hidden. It’s visible only on mouse drag. I’ve tried [NSCursor unhide] but it does not work. How can I unhide it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if you can do this from a Cocoa screen saver. There appears to be no way to ask nicely to receive mouse events rather than having those events trigger the end of the screen saver. You may need to use Carbon for this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been asked a while ago but I would suggest using a built-in function to hide the cursor and let OS X handles the unhide. There is a class method

```
[NSCursor setHiddenUntilMouseMoves:YES];
```